# PHP scoring for a quiz that involves page reloads

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a scoring system for my PHP game. However I cannot just increment a counter and increase the counter very time the user gets a question right because after one question appears and is answered correctly the page reloads and displays the new question. This results in the score only working once, ex: adds one than stays at that number for the rest of the questions. How can I set up scoring over a system like this that involves the page reloads. It needs to know if it is at the new question and to add or miss one from the score depending if the answer is right or wrong. This is my code currently in which I am actually trying to do this in:

```
<?php

$questionsAndAnwsers = array(array("question" => " What early cartoon character created by the Disney Studio was Mickey Mouse based off of ?",     "answer" => "Oswald The Lucky Rabbit"),

array("question" => "Who invented the first TV ? Please use full name.", "answer" => "Philo Taylor Farnsworth"),

array("question" => "When was Warner Brothers founded ? Format: Month Day, Year", "answer" => "April 4, 1923"), 

array("question" => "When was Superman's first appearance date ? Format: Month Year", "answer" => "June 1938"),

array("question" => "What does the acronym OWN, for the cable television channel, stand for ?", "answer" => "Oprah Winfrey Network"),

array("question" => "What type of dog is Scooby Doo from the cartoon series, Scooby Doo ?", "answer" => "Great Dane"),

array("question" => "What type of food does Garfield the cat love ?", "answer" => "Lasagna"), 

array("question" => "How many Pokemon were in Generation I ? Use number not word.", "answer" => "151"), 

//rest of arrays.. not going to show all



// current question
$currentQuestion = 0;

if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
     $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
     if(isset($questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion])){

     $currentAnswer = $questionsAndAnwsers["$currentQuestion"]["answer"];

     if($currentQuestion==15){
        header("Location:  http://students.purchase.edu/martin.mcnicholas/scriptingfortheweb/index2.html"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
     }else if($_POST["guess"] == $currentAnswer){
         $currentQuestion++;
         $guess = $_POST['guess'];
         print ("<span class='Stylize2'>Your answer: $guess <br>"); 
         print("The answer expected: $currentAnswer<br>");  
         print("Answer Correct $answerCorrect<br><br>");
         $images = [
         1 => 'MickeyMouse.png',
         2 => 'Philo.jpg',
      //more images..
  ];

  if( array_key_exists($currentQuestion, $images))
      echo "<img src='{$images[$currentQuestion]}'  alt='$images[$currentQuestion]' height='200'><br><br>";
 else
     echo "Not found";
         print("Next Question Below<br></span><br><br>");
       } 

       else {
         $currentQuestion=0;
         $guess = $_POST['guess'];
         print ("<span class='Stylize'>Your answer: $guess <br>");   
         print("You have failed..<br>"); 
         echo '<img src=angry.gif height="200"></span><br><br>';
     $test = '251993__kwahmah-02__distorted-voice-18.wav';
     echo '<audio autoplay loop>';
     echo "<source src='$test' type='audio/wav'>";
     echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element';
     echo '</audio>';
       }
       }else{
      exit("Question not found!");
       }
    }
?>
```

Normally you would be able to just increment a count after each question if right or decrease if wrong for every question and in the end just add the results of every question. But what would I do in this situation?

Comment: Hmmm.... so you need some kind of variable that persists for the whole of the user's session on the site? Have you tried `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @Spudley I haven't used sessions before and the only thing I understand how to do with them is create a session variable, the last time I tried using a session variable after creating it that is where I was lost

Comment: In that case, what you need is a tutorial in how PHP session handling works. That kind of thing is out of scope for Stackoverflow, where answers are meant to be a bit more targetted. The good news is that there are plenty of tutorials out there on this topic. Just make sure you pick one that is up-to-date (PHP language and best practice have changed quite a bit over the years, so out-of-date tutorial sites can often give very bad advice).

Comment: @Spudley I actually managed to figure it out with a bit of help from the answer below but do you actually have any good links to PHP session handling. The ones I have used and looked at are not only quite old but to be honest quite confusing. I am probably looking at some very bad documentation on it.

Comment: Sessions are a relatively simple topic (at least for the basics); there's not too much you need to know about them to start using them. It's hard for me to judge exactly what kind of tutorials will be helpful for you, but you could start at Medium.com; there's lots of good stuff there, and generally kept up-to-date. A quick search now [gave me this page](https://medium.com/@jpmorris/how-to-build-a-php-login-form-using-sessions-c7fb6d8ecebe) which looks like it might be helpful?

Comment: @Spudley Thank you and it certainly is especially since it mentions session destroy which I am actually currently working on other wise the count keeps goin up forever so if you beat the quiz and come back it will start scoring from 16 up because it was never destroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use session variable instead of normal variable 
On each webpage

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION[“count”];
```

Comment: could you explain how to actually use it?

Comment: I put the session start at the top of my PHP then declared the session variable like you showed. I then did `if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}` to set it to zero if it isn't set already. Then in my if it is correct statement I declared `$_SESSION['score'] ++` . Is this how it is done?

Comment: Yep @MartinM just use this and it will hold the value on all the web pages

Comment: oh ok hmm ok so then one more question to make sure it is working how do I actually print the results I can't just do `print("$SESSION['score']);`

Comment: echo $_SESSION[‘score’]; should work fine, also make sure session_start() is there in the page php script where you are trying to print

Comment: Ahh so you do echo session variables to print them thanks so much and yep I already had the session start in. It is working beautifully.